# how to keep array value in outside of closure function with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, closures

i used closure function to create an array. the problem is that I don't have access to the value of that array outside of this function.

```
$categorySlug=array();
    GameModel::with("user")->with("categories")->get()->each(function ($query) use ($categorySlug){
        foreach ($query["categories"] as $item){
            array_push($categorySlug,$item["slug"]);
        }
        // $categorySlug That's right here
    }); 
// $categorySlug here is empty array
```

How can I access the array value inside the function from outside the function?

Comment: Well, first of all, you need to pass `$categorySlug` into the function via `function ($query) use ($categorySlug)`. Beyond that, it should be available after the `foreach()` and the `->each()`, and should be populated, but only if `$query["categories"]` contains more than 0 elements. Are you getting any kind of error with this code?

Comment: you would have to use a reference as arrays are copy on write

Comment: @timLevis i don't have any error. just $categorySlug in outside of function is empty. but in inside function filled with many data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the keyword `use`:

```php
$categorySlug=array();
GameModel::with("user")->with("categories")->get()->each(function ($query) use (&$categorySlug) {
    foreach ($query["categories"] as $item){
        array_push($categorySlug,$item["slug"]);
    }
    // $categorySlug is available here
});
// $categorySlug is available here
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
> variables must be passed to the use language construct. As of PHP 7.1,
> these variables must not include superglobals, $this, or variables
> with the same name as a parameter.

See example #4 in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: its ok. i frogot write it. But that was not my problem

Comment: @morteza this is not the same thing as you have, the difference is an important one

Comment: @lagbox I just want to know how to access a variable inside the function from the outside. This was just an example

Comment: add the code I have put and it will work.

Comment: @alex i put it bot not working. the $categorySlug has a empty array in outside function.

Answer (score -1):

i solved it.  return the $categorySlug in the closure function. then assign it to new value.

```
$categorySlug=array();
    $categorySlug = GameModel::with("user")->with("categories")->get()->each(function ($query) use ($categorySlug){
        foreach ($query["categories"] as $item){
            array_push($categorySlug,$item->slug);
        }
        return $categorySlug;
    });
    // now $categorySlug filled with many data;
```